# ProgressDialog is not showing in android

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I know that is easy to do it, but I've tried to take some examples from here and is not showing the progressDialog. That I want to do is show a ProgressDialog when click the button and finish when the task is finished:

Thanks in advance!

```
 buttonStartOCR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(SimpleAndroidORCActivity.this, "Processing", "Please wait...", true);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                onPhotoTaken();
                            }
                        });
                    };
                }).start();
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: remove   progress.dismiss(); and check it

Answer (score 1):

Your ProgressDialog is showing but its dismissed right after the show. Put your dismiss inside the run method of your runnable.

This way:

```
 buttonStartOCR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(SimpleAndroidORCActivity.this, "Processing", "Please wait...", true);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            onPhotoTaken();
                            progress.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                };
            }).start();

    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, is in your way but is not showing correctly. Now, I can see only the progressDialog when the task is finish for a less than a second, but not when I click the button

Answer (score 0):

a thread is an independent process which runs in background your progress bar is showing and dismissing immediately, call progress.dismiss(); in your run() after your onPhotoTaken()

Comment: If I put the progress.dismiss() after onPhotoTaken() I can see the dialog for less than a second when the task is finish, but not when I click the button

Answer (score 0):

in below code you dismiss the dialog as it start also running thread so dismissing dialog can't wait for task which is inside thread.

```
buttonStartOCR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progress = ProgressDialog.show(SimpleAndroidORCActivity.this, "Processing", "Please wait...", true);
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    onPhotoTaken();
                                    progress.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                        };
                    }).start();

            }
        });
```

onPhotoTaken() :- should return any value so that we can dismiss dialog.

and dismiss dialog in main thraed

Comment: Hi. Is not working.  Now, I can see only the progressDialog when the task is finish for a less than a second, but not when I click the button and while the task is doing

Comment: can you please accept my answer if it is satiesfied your requirement